# When the word "super" is used in a subclass, what does word super force the code to do?

Tags: java, subclass, super

For Java programming. I've read through my text book, but I can't find it.

Comment: To call the super class of the current class.

Comment: Here you go : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.  If you do it like this:

```
public SubclassConstructor() {
    super("foo");
}
```

This is passing in these arguments to the parent's constructor.  If you do it like this:

```
public void subclassMethod() {
    super.methodInBoth("foo");
}

@Overrides
public void methodInBoth(String var) {

}
```

This is calling the parent's method *instead* of the child's method.  And, to solidify the lesson, if you did it like this:

```
public void subclassMethod() {
    this.methodInBoth("foo");
}

@Overrides
public void methodInBoth(String var) {

}
```

It would call the child's method *instead* of the parent's method.  If you just called `methodInBoth("foo");`, that would also call the child's.